# open external desktop application from MS office add-in

Tags: javascript, office-js, office-addins, word-addins, office-js-helpers

I am developing an MS office Web based Add-in using the latest javascript API.The add-in is dependent on an external desktop application. The external application starts a server on let's say localhost:3000, and the add-in communicate with that server from my javascript in add-in, therefore the external application must be running in order to use the add-in. I want to have a launch button in my add-in that launches the external application on desktop

The external application is a .exe and I have it's location inside the javascript of add-in. Is there a way I can execute a shell command or something similar to run that .exe file on the button trigger of my add-in?

[image: The launch button]

Comment: Have you got the solution? And is their any solution available for Apple Mac MS Office application to open/launch external application?

Comment: @RohitKale unfortunately no

Answer (score 1):

No, your web addin has no access to the local file system and cannot launch executables.
If you already have that exe installed, but not ensure it always runs, e.g. as a service?

Comment: Yes, As I mentioned the application starts a http server that my add-in communicates with. I got to make sure that the application is running when my add-in is used

Comment: Again, you can ensure that your app always runs by making it a local service.